# Assigning attr to a Jquery variable

Tags: jquery, variable-assignment, attr

I have a snippet of code here which I plan on using to detect which sections are already visible to aid in a navigation system I am working on however when I try to grab the visibility attribute I am unable to get a return. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    if(method === 'test'){
    console.log('Test Function Firing')
    var testvar = $('div#home').attr("visibility");
    if(testvar === 'visible'){
        console.log('Working')
    }
    else{console.log('Not Working')
        console.log(testvar);
        console.log("Log of call to "+$('div#home').attr("visibility"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visibility` isn't an attribute, its a [CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility).

Use `.css()` instead:

```
var testvar = $('div#home').css("visibility");
```